# Why is bromine produced at the anode when aqueous sodium bromide undergoes electrolysis?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

The electrode potential for Bromine is $\pu{+1.07V}$ whereas for Oxygen to be produced it is $\pu{+0.40V}$.

$$\ce{O2 +2H2O + 4e- -> 4OH-}$$

As the electrode potential for bromine is higher, it means bromine should be reduced rather than $\ce{OH-}$ ions.

I'm aware that the concentration affects the electrode potentials, but the question simply states 'an aqueous solution of NaBr' with no reference to concentration whatsoever, so I can only assume standard solutions.

Also, why do we not look at the electrode potentials of other possible reactions at the anode, like;

$$\ce{O2 + 4H+ + 4e– -> 2H2O}~~~~~~~(E=\pu{+1.23V})$$ or

$$\ce{HO2- + H2O + 2e– ->3OH–}~~~~~~(E=+\pu{0.88V})$$ or

$$\ce{H2O2 + 2H+ + 2e– -> 2H2O}~~~~~~~ (E=\pu{+1.77V})$$.

Why are these not viable?

Comment: You don't have a standard solution of $\ce{OH-}$ in there, otherwise things might have turned differently.

Comment: But all I'm told is that it is aqueous. How do I judge if it is a standard or non-standard solution?

Comment: What is a standard solution, come to think of it?

Comment: A solution where the concentrations of any ions is 1M

Comment: Right. Now, you've been told that it is aqueous solution of _what_?

Comment: Sodium Bromide. So the concentrations of the Hydrogen and Hydroxide ions will be much lesser than 1?
But then why will Hydrogen ions still be reduced at the cathode?

Comment: That's right! As for the reduction of hydrogen, there is really no other option. Na's potential if way too far away. Besides, even should Na be reduced, it would react instantly with water. Bromine is not like that.

Comment: The answer below suggests that water will be reduced at the cathode. And if the concentration of H+ ions in the solution was low enough (not sure how to do this without adding a base), wouldn't Sodium be reduced? Lastly, why do none of the other reactions occur? Suppose we have a very dilute solution of NaBr. Would we get oxygen by the first reaction, or would the rest also occur to some extent?

Comment: Sodium won't be reduced; you can't make the concentration of H+ low enough for that. As for the other reactions, some of them might occur to some minor extent, depending on the conditions.

Comment: I see.. thanks! Could you clarify what you mean by conditions? I'm unclear on this in general.
If we have two possible reactions, and one has a higher cell potential, will the other one not occur at all, or will it occur to a lesser extent? Also, is there some sort of approximate value which determines if one reaction will occur? For example, something like ' the difference in electrode potentials between the two reactions in question must be more than 1V for the reaction to occur even under non-standard conditions'

Comment: The reference book values of potentials are only good for the standard solutions (1M of everything). There is so-called [Nernst equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation) which tells you how the potential will change in non-standard concentrations.

Comment: Oh, I know about that, but I'm asking what do I do if I'm not given the concentrations of the ions, and still wish to make a prediction? Like, if the difference between two electrode potentials is greater than some emperical value, like 0.30V, then we can say that unless the concentrations are absurdly high or low, the higher one will undergo reduction.

Answer (score 1):

This is  how I see it:

In the electrolysis of NaBr, water is reduced at the cathode. This occurs because water is more easily reduced than are sodium ions. This is reflected in their standard reduction potential.

At cathode reduction of water occurs:

$$\ce{2H2O(l) + 2e- -> H2(g) + 2OH-(aq)}$$

And hydrogen gas is produced

At the anode, where oxidation occurs, the standard oxidation potential of water is –1.23 volts, while that for bromide ions is -1.07 volts.

The production of bromine itself has a negative electrode potential.
One of the half-reactions must be reversed to yield an oxidation.

$$\ce{Br^2- -> Br2 + 2e-}~~~~~~~ Eº -1.07$$

Remember that when one reverses a reaction, the sign of Eº (+ or –) for that reaction is also reversed.

This means that bromide ions are more easily oxidized than water.

*It is important to note: When current begins to flow, the distribution of ions around the electrodes changes, and the equilibrium electrode potentials no longer accurately apply.*

I think other factors also apply;

- Concentration
- Temperature
- Nature of ions

Comment: Why is water reduced at the cathode? Shouldn't it be Hydrogen ions since they have an electrode potential of 0 V? Also, could you write the reaction in which water is reduced? The 1.23V reaction I know has Oxygen being reduced, not water.

Comment: I added the equation showing reduction of water at cathode

Comment: The electrode potential for the reduction of water is -0.83V whereas for H+ ions, it is 0.00V. As such, shouldn't Hydrogen ions be reduced? Also, why are you considering the +1.23V reaction of water rather than the +0.40V one?

Comment: And where are you  generating the hydrogen ions from in the first place?  Please show the reaction that you are referring to. Also read Ivan Neretin's comments they essentially answer your additional questions

Comment: The hydrogen ions come from the water present

H2O <---> H+ +OH-